# Strange code inserted into webpage when viewed in Web Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, html

I am using NoteTab Light as my text editor to create local webpages and Firefox mainly as the browser, with "Web Developer Tools" activated when there is an error.

There is a strange set of script tags injected into the html head code block, seen when viewed with the Web Developer Tools.  I wasn't able to copy it (option locked/grayed out), but someone else was able to:

```
<script>(function(){class RuffleMimeType{constructor(a,b,c){this.type=a,this.description=b,this.suffixes=c}}class RuffleMimeTypeArray{constructor(a){this.__mimetypes=[],this.__named_mimetypes={};for(let b of a)this.install(b)}install(a){let b=this.__mimetypes.length;this.__mimetypes.push(a),this.__named_mimetypes[a.type]=a,this[a.type]=a,this[b]=a}item(a){return this.__mimetypes[a]}namedItem(a){return this.__named_mimetypes[a]}get length(){return this.__mimetypes.length}}class RufflePlugin extends RuffleMimeTypeArray{constructor(a,b,c,d){super(d),this.name=a,this.description=b,this.filename=c}install(a){a.enabledPlugin||(a.enabledPlugin=this),super.install(a)}}class RufflePluginArray{constructor(a){this.__plugins=[],this.__named_plugins={};for(let b of a)this.install(b)}install(a){let b=this.__plugins.length;this.__plugins.push(a),this.__named_plugins[a.name]=a,this[a.name]=a,this[b]=a}item(a){return this.__plugins[a]}namedItem(a){return this.__named_plugins[a]}get length(){return this.__plugins.length}}const FLASH_PLUGIN=new RufflePlugin("Shockwave Flash","Shockwave Flash 32.0 r0","ruffle.js",[new RuffleMimeType("application/futuresplash","Shockwave Flash","spl"),new RuffleMimeType("application/x-shockwave-flash","Shockwave Flash","swf"),new RuffleMimeType("application/x-shockwave-flash2-preview","Shockwave Flash","swf"),new RuffleMimeType("application/vnd.adobe.flash-movie","Shockwave Flash","swf")]);function install_plugin(a){navigator.plugins.install||Object.defineProperty(navigator,"plugins",{value:new RufflePluginArray(navigator.plugins),writable:!1}),navigator.plugins.install(a),0<a.length&&!navigator.mimeTypes.install&&Object.defineProperty(navigator,"mimeTypes",{value:new RuffleMimeTypeArray(navigator.mimeTypes),writable:!1});for(var b=0;b<a.length;b+=1)navigator.mimeTypes.install(a[b])}install_plugin(FLASH_PLUGIN);})();</script>
```

Does anyone know what this is, let alone why someone would be using shockwave, flash, or swf?

Comment: local webpages ... so you're not hosting them on some web server on the internets? It could also be some extension in Firefox doing that - what extensions do you have? - i.e. in about:addons extensions

Comment: nope, local only, from text editor to browser and back again for editing. plain jane javascript, no node, jquery, or any other library. Firefox is my main browser because, well it always works for me where the others find something to internally break. Chrome is a distant second and IE family is never.  Funny thing is that that code isn't always injected. The end run is for GUI interfaces for my ESP32 webserver microcontroller (K.I.S.S. method - keep it simple showoff, I used showoff in place of the usual term). as for extensions just youtube downloader - I don't always have internet at home.

Answer (score 0):

[This library](https://github.com/ruffle-rs/ruffle) produces this code. If you have not installed it, possibly one of your dependenencies is dependant of this library